# Laravel collect to array

Tags: php, laravel

I try to get my products visits number into charts where I can show it just like google-analytic

#### example

```
Product1   200 visits
product5   30 visits
product10  47visits
```

Now what I'm using as chart is [this package](https://github.com/ConsoleTVs/Charts)

## Here is my chart code:

```
$chartjson = Pagevisit::all()->toJson();
  $chartjsontitle =
      DB::table('products')
      ->join('page-visits', function ($join) {
          $join->on('products.id', '=', 'page-visits.visitable_id');
      })->get();
$value = collect($chartjsontitle)->toArray();

$chart4 = Charts::database($chartjson, 'bar', 'highcharts')
         ->elementLabel("Total")
         ->dimensions(1000, 500)
         ->responsive(false)
         ->values('visitable_id')
         ->labels($value);
```

As you can see my visits count will save in `page-visits` table and what I want to do is o get count of that in my chart and as label get product title.

### Progress:

- I've done getting count of my visits already

> $chartjson = Pagevisit::all()->toJson();
>           //....
>       ->values('visitable_id')

- I **couldn't** get my products title as labels for those counts.

Error I'm getting currently is:

> array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given

## UPDATE

I managed to get my info  + their title

[image: screenshot]

#### Here is the code

```
$chartjson = Pagevisit::all()->pluck('visitable_id')->toArray();
      $chartjsontitle =
          DB::table('products')
          ->join('page-visits', function ($join) {
              $join->on('products.id', '=', 'page-visits.visitable_id');
          })->pluck('title')->toArray();

      $chart4 = Charts::database($chartjson, 'bar', 'highcharts')
         ->elementLabel("Total")
         ->dimensions(1000, 500)
         ->responsive(false)
         ->values($chartjson)
         ->labels($chartjsontitle);
```

## ISSUE

I have 2 products which have visits counted but as you see for each count I have one bar except 1 bar for all counts.

- example: 1 bar with title product1 and count of 11 visits, but now I have 11 bars with title product1

Comment: Where are you calling `array_push()`?

Comment: @ObsidianAge I don't!

Comment: I think `$chartjson` is a string. Does the `Charts::database()` method's first argument is an array or it can be string? One thing you can try is to remove the `toJson` call from your Eloquent query.

Comment: @Wreigh  here is sample  `$chart = Charts::realtime(url('/path/to/json'), 2000, 'gauge', 'google')
            ->values([65, 0, 100])
            ->labels(['First', 'Second', 'Third'])
            ->responsive(false)
            ->height(300)
            ->width(0)
            ->title("Permissions Chart")
            ->valueName('value'); //This determines the json index for the value`

Comment: when you call `values()`, try to pass an array instead of a string. E.g., `values(['visitable_id'])`.

Comment: @Wreigh OK, now i get this `Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught ErrorException: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string `

Comment: @Wreigh Probebly from here `->labels($value);`

Comment: @Wreigh I updated my question please take a look.

Comment: I'm sorry, my current network blocks the imgur link :(

Comment: @Wreigh  https://ibb.co/gakVx6

Comment: take a look at the values of `$chartJson` and `$chartJsonTitle`. there could be duplicates.

Comment: @Wreigh Here is screenshot of their dd()       https://ibb.co/ko7w4m  -  
https://ibb.co/gZRZqR

Comment: your chart is displaying the right results, you have to fix your query.

Comment: @Wreigh what does that mean? this dd came from query.

Comment: yes, the result of your query returned duplicate product names, you're having 11 bars because in the result, you have 11 strings of product names.

Comment: @Wreigh can you help with query?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161415/discussion-between-wreigh-and-mafortis).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLVED (in different way)

Well I gave up upon chart for this matter and decided to use list object instead and here is the solution [Get value with max amount in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47898678/get-value-with-max-amount-in-laravel/47898770#47898770)