# Get value with max amount in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using [laravel-page-view-counter](https://github.com/cyrildewit/laravel-page-view-counter) to count visits of my products and it's working just fine, what i need to do is to get list of top 10 products by their visits (get 10 products which has largest number of visits).

Here is what I have:

```
$visits = Product::join('page-visits', function ($join) {
  $join->on('products.id', '=', 'page-visits.visitable_id');
})->get();
$sorted = $visits->sortBy(function ($product, $key) {
  return count($product['visits']);
});
```

But It return from lowest product visits to highest one (it shows product with 0 visit till product with 100 visits) I need reverse method of that to show (product with 100 visits first).

Comment: It's quit difficult to understand, if you use simple raw query it will be easier

Comment: @SagarGautam `$visits` I get my products with their visits in ` page-visits` table.  `$sorted` I sorted my `$visits` query. is it difficult?

Comment: Okay, I've added my answer take a moment to try it if any problem feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it easily with query builder and some raw queries like this:

```
$visits = DB::table('products')
            ->join('page-visits','products.id','=','page-visits.visitable_id')
            ->select(DB::raw('count(visitable_id) as count'),'products.*')
            ->groupBy('id')
            ->orderBy('count','desc')
            ->take(10)
            ->get();
```

I hope you will understand.

Comment: Ok its seems working but now i'm not able to get number of visits for each product it give me error of `Undefined property: stdClass::$page_visits_formatted` before i could get visits like `{{$visit->page_visits_formatted}}`

Comment: you should use `{{$visit->count}}` instead of `{{$visit->page_visits_formatted}}` for that since count contains total no of visits in the query i've added above

Comment: and this count will be formatted or no? formatted is like `1.000` if not is like `1000`

Comment: @mafortis pardon me,  I don't understand what you are saying about formatting :)

Comment: Bro formatted count will return numbers with `.` (dot) if number is bigger than 3 digit example `1.000.000` as you see after each 3 digit has one dot.

Comment: @mafortis I've understand but i'm not familiar with how such formatting works in php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161569/discussion-between-mafortis-and-sagar-gautam).